# Change color of mouse cursor in JTextField?

Tags: java, colors, cursor

I want to change the color of Mouse cursor in JTextField, not blinking cursor but,  Mouse cursor when I place the mouse in JTextField?

Comment: Well, if you want that, you should write code to do that.

Comment: You can find it easily in Google. No need for Stack assist.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a MouseMotionListener on your JTextfield.
and do something like:

```
 textfield.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.CUSTOM_CURSOR));
```

you'd have to change the custom cursor ofc.

Comment: Thanks for the help but i don't want to change the cursor type. I want to change the COLOR of cursor when we hover cursor on JTextField. You know that Capital i cursor.

Comment: capital i would be the blinking one but hovering over it doesn't match that so I'm out.